# spring aop and jersey classes

Tags: spring, jersey, aop

so in spring xml config, i define the following pointcut:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="metricsAdviceInterceptor">
        <aop:around method="invoke" pointcut="@annotation(com.mycom.MetricsAdvice)"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

The idea is to collect metrics on methods that have the  "MetricsAdvice" annotation:

```
class SomeClass {
    @MetricsAdvice
    public void someMethod(...) { ... }
}
```

So this all works fine when i explicitly declare the beans in my spring config:

```
 <bean id="someBean" class="com.mycom.SomeClass" />
```

But i want to be able to use this annotation on jersey code, and it doesn't work. Now, in the jersey config, one adds the below to web.xml. The idea is that you're telling jersey in which packages to find various rest services. Ie, it looks for classes in the packages: com.mycom.restservices.* and instantiates them. Presumably the instantiation of these beans is being done "differently", and thus aren't getting proxied:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyWebApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <display-name>Jersey Servlet</display-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.mycom.restservices.billing;
            com.mycom.restservices.account;
            org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    ....
```

So what's "best practice" for trying to get these annotations to work on jersey beans?

Thx.

Comment: This (old) question is for Jersey 1, but users of Jersey 2 might find the issue [JERSEY-2301](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2301) relevant

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to get rid of explicit bean declarations, you can use Spring classpath scanning feature instead of the Jersey one.

Just annotate your Jersey resources with `@Component` (or other similar annotations), and use `<context:component-scan>` to specify packages with these resources.

This way beans will be instantiated by Spring, and Spring AOP will work fine.

**See also:**

- [3.10 Classpath scanning and managed components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning)

Comment: It doesn't work, presumably because of the "who instantiates/uses it?" issue. If jersey is instantiating and using the beans directly; it doesn't matter if i'm also instantiating them in spring. I'm not getting the instance i want; the proxied instance.

Comment: @Jack: Have you tried to remove these init-params from web.xml as well?

Comment: I did, and it doesn't work because presumably when jersey instantiates the bean it does the wiring necessary to expose this as a rest service. So if i remove it from web.xml, my rest service does not exist. I logged a stack trace in the ctor for this bean when i do have the config in web.xml; and you can see the bean being instantiated twice; once from spring, and once from jersey code. Completely different code paths.